# Find the number of solutions to $ \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 4x \rfloor + \ldots + \lfloor 32x \rfloor =12345$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the number of solutions of the equation 
>   $$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 4x \rfloor + \lfloor 8x \rfloor + \lfloor 16x \rfloor + \lfloor 32x \rfloor =12345,$$
>   where $\lfloor\,\cdot\,\rfloor$ represents the floor function.

My work:
I use the fact that
$$\lfloor nx \rfloor =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left\lfloor x +\frac kn \right\rfloor.$$
So the equation becomes
$$\lfloor x \rfloor +\sum_{k=0}^{1} \left\lfloor x +\frac k2 \right\rfloor +\sum_{k=0}^{3} \left\lfloor x +\frac k4 \right\rfloor +\sum_{k=0}^{7} \left\lfloor x +\frac k8 \right\rfloor   \\
\qquad {}+\sum_{k=0}^{15} \left\lfloor x +\frac k{16} \right\rfloor +\sum_{k=0}^{31} \left\lfloor x+\frac k{32} \right\rfloor   \\
= \lfloor x \rfloor + \left\lfloor x+\frac 12 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor x+\frac 64 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor x+\frac{28}{8} \right\rfloor   \\
\qquad {}+ \left\lfloor x+\frac{120}{16} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor x+\frac{496}{32} \right\rfloor$$

What should I do next?

Comment: Did you mean [] is the floor function? If so, please write it in the post, not only in a tag. "Greatest integer function" is unclear.

Comment: Yes,I have written greatest integer function in question

Comment: Do you mean [n] is the greatest integer _smaller than or equal to_ n? You should make that clearer. (in the question, not in a tag)

Comment: It is floor function

Comment: Wait, so _x_ can be any real number?

Comment: It is not provided in question

Comment: Okay, I'll try.

Comment: BTW, the notation $[x]$ for greatest integer not $>x$, is a bit old fashioned.  Modern books tend to use the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: Ok,I will keep this in mind for future

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no solutions. For $x\to196^-$ the function value is $12342$, and for $x=196$ it is $12348$, with no values in between.

Comment: Without putting value there is no way to solve it ?

Comment: @AakashKumar: Not sure what you mean by "without putting value". I solved the corresponding equation without the floor functions, $63x=12345$, yielding $x=\frac{12345}{63}\approx195.95$, which shows that any solution would have to be between that value and $196$; then it just remains to find the limit as $x\to196^-$, which you get by noting that each floor function drops by $1$ when $x$ drops below an integer.

Comment: How it show that x must lies between $x=195.95 and 196$

Comment: @AakashKumar: Since the floor function is at most equal to its argument, we need at least $x=\frac{12345}{63}$, since that would solve the equation without any deductions from the floor functions. On the other hand, since for integer $x$ the floor function is equal to its argument, we must have $x\lt 196$, since $x=\frac{12345}{63}$ is already enough if we replace the floor functions by their arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Your work, while a reasonable approach, does not lead to the answer. A slightly simpler approach does:

Let $p \in \Bbb{Z} = \lfloor x \rfloor$ and let $x= p +q$ with $0\leq q < 1$.

Then the left hand side is

$$L = 63p + \lfloor q\rfloor + \lfloor 2q\rfloor+ \lfloor 4q\rfloor+ \lfloor 8q\rfloor+ \lfloor 16q\rfloor+ \lfloor 32q\rfloor \geq 63p \\
L = 12345 \implies 12345 \geq 63p  \implies p \leq 12345/63 < 196
$$ 
$$L = 63p + \lfloor q\rfloor + \lfloor 2q\rfloor+ \lfloor 4q\rfloor+ \lfloor 8q\rfloor+ \lfloor 16q\rfloor+ \lfloor 32q\rfloor \leq 63p + 1+3+7+15+31 \\
L = 12345 \implies 12345 \leq 63p + 57 \implies p \geq 12288/63 > 195
$$ 
So if a solution exists, then $p$ is an integer between about $195.05$ and $195.95$.  No such integer exists, the the number of solutions is zero.

Comment: You probably wanted to say $p\leq \frac{12345}{63}<196$, which I took the liberty to edit, along with two other typos.

Comment: @Mark Shouldn't it be $12345\ge63p\ge12345-57$?

Comment: In your step ofsecond left hand side you have taken 195.95<195

Answer (score 5):

Let 
$$
f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 4x \rfloor
+ \lfloor 8x \rfloor + \lfloor 16x \rfloor + \lfloor 32x \rfloor.
$$
For integers $n$ we have $f(n)=63n$, but for a small number to the left of $n$ all terms $\lfloor x \rfloor, \lfloor 2x \rfloor,\dots$ decrease by one. So at every integer $n$ we have that $f$ jumps from $63n-6$ to $63n$. By calculation we have $$f(196)=12348,$$ so at $n=196$ we find that $f$ jumps from $12342$ to $12348$. Since $f$ is increasing we find that $f(x)=12345$ has no solutions.

Answer (score 3):

**Alt. solution:** Write the fractional part of $x$ in binary:
$$
x = n + 0.b_1 b_2 b_3 \ldots = n + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{2^i},
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b_i \in \{0,1\}$.
Also give your function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a name:
$$
f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 4x \rfloor + \lfloor 8x \rfloor + \lfloor 16x \rfloor + \lfloor 32x \rfloor 
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 4x \rfloor + \lfloor 8x \rfloor + \lfloor 16x \rfloor + \lfloor 32x \rfloor \\
&= n + (2n + b_1) + (4n + 2b_1 + b_2) + \cdots + (32n + 16b_1 + 8b_2 + 4b_3 + 2b_4 + b_5) \\
&= 63n + 31b_1 + 15b_2 + 7b_3 + 3b_4 + b_5.
\end{align*}
We can choose $b_i \in \{0,1\}$ arbitrarily,
so it follows that the image of $f$ is exactly
the set of integers whose remainder is between $0$ and $31 + 15 + 7 + 3 + 1 = 57$, mod $63$.
In particular, $12345 \equiv 60 \pmod{63}$, so $12345$ is not in the image of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\underset{{n}=\mathrm{0}} {\overset{\mathrm{5}} {\sum}}\lfloor\mathrm{2}^{{n}} {x}\rfloor=\mathrm{12345} \\ $$
$${x}\underset{{n}=\mathrm{0}} {\overset{\mathrm{5}} {\sum}}\left(\mathrm{2}^{{n}} −{f}_{{n}} \right)=\mathrm{12345} \\ $$
$$\mathrm{63}{x}=\left[\mathrm{12345};\mathrm{12351}\right) \\ $$
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{196} \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{2}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{392} \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{4}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{784} \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{8}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{1568} \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{16}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{3136} \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{32}{x}\rfloor=\left[\mathrm{6271};\mathrm{6273}\right] \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{32}{x}\rfloor=\underset{{n}=\mathrm{0}} {\overset{\mathrm{5}} {\sum}}\lfloor\mathrm{2}^{{n}} {x}\rfloor−\underset{{n}=\mathrm{0}} {\overset{\mathrm{4}} {\sum}}\lfloor\mathrm{2}^{{n}} {x}\rfloor \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{32}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{6269} \\ $$
$$\left[{NO}\:{SOLUTION}\right] \\ $$